# What's the perfect internal storage preserving technique? Does link2sd and data2sd interfere?

Tags: internal-storage, app2sd, link2sd

I have a **rooted** ZTE Blade with a fast 8 Gbyte SD card (it's **fast** enough, and **partitioned** to 6G + 2G) running on **CM7**, and I'm using [LINK2SD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD), but I'm not perfectly happy with it. Altough, LINK2SD is far better than APP2SD I've used before, and all the apps are now linked to SD card, but somehow, I'm just getting *low on internal space*. I've read somewhere that private data is what remains on the internal storage. How can I kick everything out of that internal storage?

- Can I use [DATA2SD](https://market.android.com/details?id=rappsd.v1) and LINK2SD together?
- What about [Simple2Ext](https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.krikun.s2e)?

Also, I've read that Titanium Backup can install stock app updates to the System partition. (That one thing I haven't done yet, my System partition on internal storage is "too big", I should repartition it.)

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Titanium Backup can replace system apps with their updated versions.  Ordinarily the original versions of system apps are always kept even if they've been updated, wasting a significant amount of space.  You can do it manually of course, but need root.  TB's much easier.

Comment: Transferring apps to system area (even not really system apps) is a good way to utilize the system partition without re-partitioning the internal storage, but it does not helps much more on the small size of the user partition of internal storage, Link2SD does similar job. I wanna forget internal user partition. (Maybe, I'm wrong.)

Comment: Unfortunately Link2SD does not work with Android 6 so I have to use the App Apps2SD. As I see with Apps2SD you can even link more data of linked Apps than with Link2SD

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Pro Version of Link2SD, then you will be able to move everything of the APP(Apk,Dex,Lib,Data and Cache) onto the second partition of the SD card.And thus you won't be using any internal memory. My Phone has 157mb internal memory and I have apps that would have allredy filled it installed on my phone without losing space.

[image: Example] [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the data that's eating up most of the space, at least on my Lenovo P780. The good news is that the latest version of Link2SD allows you to also move data files to the memory card. The bad news is that if you were already using Link2SD with a second partition formatted as FAT32, then you'll need to reformat that partition to a non-FAT file system (ext2, ext3, ext4, or f2fs). In summary, here's what you'll need to do:

1. Remove all symlinks created by Link2SD. You may need to uninstall some apps if you're running low on internal memory.
2. Use a partition manager to format the second partition on the memory card as Ext2, Ext3, or Ext4.
3. Update Link2SD to the latest version and create the links again.